# What is the difference between use-case diagram and sequence diagram in unified process model?

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram, use-case-diagram

I'm studying UML and I am confused.Could anyone explain me What is the difference between use-case diagram and sequence diagram in unified process model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use-case diagram shows the objectives that make external actors interact with the system. It‘s about **relations** with the **outside** world. Each use-case is independent and **not sequenced** with the others.

The sequence diagram shows a scenario of interaction between objects **within** the system. The interaction in the diagram correspond to **message** that are exchanged in a given **sequence**.